# Saving AngularJS template as string

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I may just be confusing myself here.  But I have a view with a combination of variables and text.  And I need to store the entire contents as a string inside my model. ie.

```
<h3>
  {{vars.color}} is my color: {{theme.color.black}};
</h3>
```

I'm hoping to be able to save the string to:

```
{{preference.string}} // as 'base is my color: #000'
```

I have no problem displaying the text.  But I want to save the whole string.  (As if I could add ng-model) to the 'h3' tag.  But that doesn't work.

Should I be doing this in a function or directive instead?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, you want to save the _rendered result_ of Angular code to a string?

Comment: Hi @BenjaminGruenbaum, yes.  Exactly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally **it is considered bad to touch the DOM from a controller**.

However, in your case I don't see other options and as you're only *reading* from the DOM and not manipulating it in any way it's not as bad.

Assuming you have the text rendered in a controller, you can use `$element` to gain access to the element and then fetch the text content. Again, this is a last resort and against the Angular philosophy.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", [])
app.controller("HomeController", HomeController);

function HomeController($scope,$element) {
    $scope.vars = {};
    $scope.vars.color = "Black";
    $scope.theme = {color:{}};
    $scope.theme.color.black = "#000000";

    $scope.snap = function(){
        alert($element.find("h3").text()); // will alert the text
    }
}
```

#### [Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/TPU8E/2/)

Alternatively, you can decouple this logic from a controller (and the used DOM) completely using `$compile`. This is a rather long example but it gives you a peek into Angular's way of doing things, this doesn't require an app.

```
var $inj = angular.injector(["ng"]); // get access to Angular's services
var template = "<h3>{{vars.color}} is my color: {{theme.color.black}}</h3>"

//now let's access the compilation service, and also a scope service and get a new scope.
var $compile = $inj.get("$compile");
var $scope = $inj.get("$rootScope").$new(true);

// put our stuff in this new scope
$scope.vars = {color:"White"};
$scope.theme = {color:{black:"#000000"}};

// add the template 
var ngTemplate = $compile(angular.element(template));
var result = ngTemplate($scope); 
$scope.$apply(); // tell angular to apply changes to the scope
console.log(result.text()); // now we have our rendered text.
// calling $destroy on the scope here is probably good ;)
```

#### [here is a fiddle for that](http://jsfiddle.net/bg3mw/)

However, are you sure what you're looking for is not partial views? What is the *purpose* of this?

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to do this...  I think $compile might be what I'm looking for.  I definitely understand about keeping DOM manipulation out of the controller.  I really just need to be able to send the contents of the rendered string off to an API.  (it gets parsed on the other side).  I'm thinking I could just do this all manually in a function as well  (there's just a lot of lines).  But I was just wondering if there was a $compile hook of some sort.   Thanks for pointing me in this direction.  I'll dig through it and report back shortly.

Comment: I guess I'm really just looking for jQuery(el).html() at the end of the day :)  Your answer has me thinking about a couple possibilities...  Report back in a bit.

Comment: You don't need to do `el`, Angular will hook on jQuery and will let you use `.html` directly on `$element`. Glad I could help.

Comment: You definitely did.  And yeah, just tested, and it works.  Going to put it in a service.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think its good to have directive to embed a different html content.  you can do something like this.

```
<h3 show-data>
</h3>
```

Directive :

```
 angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.vars.color = "base";
    $scope.theme.color.black = "#000";
  })
  .directive('showData', function() {
    return {
      template: '{{vars.color}} is my color: {{theme.color.black}}'
    };
  });
```

Scope Changes in controller:

```
$scope.preference.string = $scope.vars.color + "is my color: " + $scope.theme.color.black;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm not sure I'm following...  I see how this will display my code.  But I want to save the value back to my object as a string.  How would I associate the returned value with a model?

Comment: Oh.. If you want to do it manually.  I will update the changes

Comment: This really doesn't solve OP's issue. The text here is a simple example. OP wants to use Angular for templating strings.

Comment: Exactly what @BenjaminGruenbaum said.  I want to store a template string with the rendered code. Thanks again for looking.

Comment: As an example.  I want to save the value of template: in the directive above, into a string in my model.